# Printing each step of a Tower of Hanoi using Arrays

Tags: java, debugging, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to print each step of a Tower of Hanoi using an array of objects. The objects I'm using are Pokemon objects with  only a name. It does have other attributes that are irrelevant to this code. I'm using only the names to sort the Tower. The Array of Pokemon objects is sorted by alphabetical order using this code below:

```
for ( int i = 0; i<pokemon.length;i++){
    for ( int j = i+1; j<pokemon.length; j++){
        if ( (pokemon[j].getName().compareTo(pokemon[i].getName())<0)){
            String temp = pokemon[i].getName();
            pokemon[i].setName(pokemon[j].getName());
            pokemon[j].setName(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

After the array is properly sorted, I then created this print method to display the Tower of Hanoi process happening.

```
static public void printArray(int n, Pokemon[] a, Pokemon[] b, Pokemon[] c) {
    String slot1 = "";
    String slot2 = "";
    String slot3 = "";
    System.out.println("A\t\tB\t\tC");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!a[i].getName().equals("")) {
            slot1 = a[i].getName();
            if (!b[i].getName().equals("")) {
                slot2 = b[i].getName();
                if (!c[i].getName().equals("")) {
                    slot3 = c[i].getName();
                } else
                    slot3 = "";
            } else
                slot2 = "";
        } else
            slot1 = "";
        System.out.println(slot1 + "\t\t" + slot2 + "\t\t" + slot3);
    }

}
```

I understand that using \t to format is a poor choice, but for debugging purposes this is functional for now, I hope to convert it to printf for a better format. The purpose of this printArray method is to print the  A B C array's from a top down view.

For every element in the array that does not have a name, i.e. it was never set to anything, it does not print it. This way it only prints the 'action' that is happening. I've verified this by using setName with both random Strings and empty Strings("") to see if it printed correctly, it does.

Next I decided to take a stab at the actual recursion method itself and ended up with this mess

```
static public void Hanoi(int n, Pokemon[] a, Pokemon[] b, Pokemon[] c){

    int a1 =n;
    int b1 =n-1;
    int c1 =n-1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        if ( !a[i].getName().equals("")){
            a1--;
        }
        if ( !b[i].getName().equals("")){
            b1--;
        }
        if ( !c[i].getName().equals("")){
            c1--;
        }

    }

    if ( n > 0 ){
        printArray(n, a, b,c);
        Hanoi(n-1, a, c, b);
        c[c1].setName(a[a1].getName());CC
        a[a1].setName("");

        Hanoi(n-1,b, a, c);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

    }
}
```

N is the number the user enters ( 'Numbers of disks' )

I should also comment this but I tend to want to make sure my program works before commenting and having everything get messy. The point of the if statements is to decrement the index counters for each individual array (A,B,C) if there is a name already in the array. The higher the index means the bottom of the stack, literally.

I'm fairly lost now and have no idea what to be checking but I'm doing what I can with little bugtests but if anyone has had experience with this and give me some advice or point something out, I would appreciate it!

Note: I'm a student studying OOP right now so my tools are limited to what we have already learned, therefore I'm trying to do this with what I already know, Arrays to handle the Tower of Hanoi Recursive Method.

EDIT: Sorry, it was late at night and I was extremely tired and not thinking clearly to post a logical question. The issue I'm having is tracing back my logic. I get confused when I get to the recursive function calls.

If I enter a 3, the most simple of Tower of Hanoi problems, then I get this sample output

```
3
A       B       C
Bulbasaur               
Pikachu             
Squirtle                
A       B       C
Bulbasaur               
Pikachu             
A       B       C
Bulbasaur
```

The method call is

```
Hanoi(3,pokemon,b,c)
```

Tracing back the logic I end up with a1 = 0, b1, = 2, and c1 = 2, which corresponds with the first print for all the indexes

```
 A      B       C
Bulbasaur               
Pikachu             
Squirtle
```

This is where I get confused , when I call the Hanoi(n-1,a,c,b) does the code end up printing 2 times before the outermost loop is finished? If so, I can't decide where to put the print statement because I need the output to only print once every time something changes.

For the regular Tower of Hanoi I think I understand the print line

```
System.out.println("Moving a stack from", A, C)
```

However when dealing with Arrays I need to set a value somewhere into the C array and remove a value from the A array, effectively causing a "move", which I have in the lines

```
c[c1].setName(a[a1].getName());
a[a1].setName("");
```

If this logic happens after the recursive function call, does that mean that it resolves the innermost loop first? So when n = 1? At this point I'm completely lost because I know that calling the recursive function with

```
Hanoi(n-1,a,c,b)
```

means that everytime it does the destination and auxilary array are being switched around, I can't wrap my head around this. Where do I use the print statements. How does the recursive function calls affect my shifting of the disks, is there a better way to deal with Tower of Hanoi with Arrays then using individual indexes to keep track of each Array, because it seems to not work after the Arrays are switched from their original position.

Comment: You put up a lot of code and text. But I dont get what you are asking us to help you with. Hint: we are not here to figure if your solution is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking. What are you stuck with?